# Boost Graph Library Undirected Graph No parallel edges enforcement

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using the Boost Graph Library to process an undirected graph, and declared my graph has

```
typedef property<vertex_index_t, int, property<vertex_name_t, string> > VertexProperty;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, setS, undirectedS, VertexProperty > UndirectedGraph;
```

As you can see, the OutEdgeList is of the type std::set and I chose it because the documentation says that this type will enforce the absence of parallel edges.

Now, my program reads a text file which indicates edges between nodes, creates the nodes if not previously seen and adds the edge between them.

I recently run the code with a large amount of data and found strange results. After some hours I discovered some user which had more degree than the number of vertices in the graph, so I tried the code with a simple text file that only described two edges between the same pair of nodes but with reversed source,target, such that boost will execute the following:

```
add_edge(A,B)
add_edge(B,A)
```

And noticed Boost ended up adding both edges. out_degree returns 2 for both of them.

Now, the question: am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't add_edge(a,b) be the same as add_edge(b,a) for an undirected graph with setS as the OutEdgeList type?

Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the OutEdgeList is the first template parameter, not the second, so I was in fact using vecS and not setS.

Comment: Have you really solved the problem? I still have this problem even OutEdgeList is set to `setS`, since `setS` still treat the edge `(A,B)` not equal to `(B, A)` even in undirected graph.

Comment: @xuhdev It works for me: https://gist.github.com/daviddoria/3a95428c85057c2b404ef9193083a6c3